# jquery functions dont work on dom elements loaded asynchromously

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I wrote **jQuery** event handlers on **DOM** elements that are not yet in the page but might be loaded asynchronously into the page. What I observed was these event handlers seem to not recognize that some new elements were added to the **DOM** and that they need to act on them on triggering.

Am I right in my observation? How do I achieve this functionality?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346346/jquery-selector-doesnt-update-after-dynamically-adding-new-elements/9346385#9346385) to another question for a good description of your jQuery options for solving this problem with `.on()` or `.delegate()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want event handlers to work on dynamically added content, you need to use `on`

```
$(document).on("click", "someCssSelector", function(){
    //your code here
});
```

Of course this will cause all clicks anywhere on your page to be watched.  To be more efficient, see if you can structure your page so that all of these elements whose `click` event you want to handle will be in **one** container.  ie, if all of these elements are going to be added to a div with an id of `foo`, you'd write the above more efficiently as

```
$("#foo").on("click", "someCssSelector", function(){
    //your code here
});
```

---

If you're using jQuery < 1.7, you'd use delegate

```
$(document).delegate("someCssSelector", "click", function(){
    //your code here
});
```

Comment: @SLaks - I'm getting to that :)

Comment: @SLaks what does root mean here?

Comment: @AdamRackis Is there a way of mentioning to js that it should always check for all the loaded DOM elements globally instead of using 'on' in each event function?

Answer (score 1):

> Am I right in my observation?

Yes.

> How do I achieve this functionality?

Using the [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function to subscribe to those event handlers if you are using jQuery 1.7+:

```
$(document).on('click', '.someSelector', function() {
    ...
});
```

or using the [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) function if you are using an older version (higher than 1.4.3):

```
$(document).delegate('.someSelector', 'click', function() {
    ...
});
```

For both you could use a more specific root than `document` to improve performance if you know that those elements will be added to some container for example.

And if you are using some prehistoric version you could go with [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
$('.someSelector').live('click', function() {
    ...
});
```