# login div using jQuery called from an anchor tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a jquery for login that opens a new div in the middle while the rest of the page fades. It works if I use an anchor tag with the **class='login-window'** and the jquery selects it using:

```
$('a.login-window').click(function() {
});
```

But when i move the anchor tag into a div that i fill using ajax at runtime:

```
<div id="nav">
  <ul class="dropdown dropdown-horizontal">
    <li><a href="#login-box"  class="login-window">Log In</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

how do I get it to work from within the list??

Answer (score 2):

Any DOM elements that were added after the page has loaded won't work correctly, you need to use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) which will check for elements added afterwards using javascript and apply any jQuery to them.

```
$("body").on("click", "p", function(){
    //
});
```

EDIT: Or [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) if you have to use an older jQuery.

Comment: Use `.on()` instead of `.live()`.

Comment: Your edit should really read "Or [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) if you have to use an older jQuery.", since that's the suggested function for older versions.

Comment: Older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()`.  `.live()` is never recommended any more.

Answer (score 0):

Just answered this same question yesterday in detail: [jQuery selector doesn't update after dynamically adding new elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346346/jquery-selector-doesnt-update-after-dynamically-adding-new-elements/9346385#9346385).

The answer is to use `.on()` or `.delegate()` (depending upon which jQuery version you have) so you can use delegated event handling rather than direct element event handling.

In your case, if the `#nav` object is the parent of all these links, then you would use this:

```
$('#nav').on('click', 'a.login-window', function() {
    // your code here
});
```

If `#nav` isn't the parent of all the links, then you need to find some common parent to use in the jQuery object.  The events from all the dynamically created objects will bubble up to the common parent and be filtered and handled there.