# Click event on cloned element of same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I am cloning a row when a button is pressed in a row. The row contains the button being pressed, therefore when cloned a new row is added below, meaning there is another button. The button states "Add" but changes to "Remove" when add is pressed. The problem I'm having is that I want the `click()` function to check the last instance of the button/class, instead but it remains checking the original button. I want it to check the last button.

Take a look at the jsfiddle to see what I am trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fogest/4gdJk/

My issue is not changing the name of the buttons to "Remove", but I want to know how should I be applying this click function to the last button that is added?

Edit: Using jQuery v1.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.on` instead `.click`  here is [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on("click", ".add-remove-new:last", function () {
    $('tr.newService:first').clone().insertAfter($('tr.newService:last'));
});
```

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4gdJk/2/)

or you can use `.live` for jquery 1.6.1

```
$('.add-remove-new:last').live('click', function() {
    $('tr.newService:first').clone().insertAfter($('tr.newService:last'));
});
```

[demo for 1.6.1](http://jsfiddle.net/4gdJk/3/)

Comment: version added: 1.7 but you can use migrate https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/

Comment: Any alternative ways of doing this without utilizing other software?

Comment: Thanks, that works. You can edit your answer if you'd like to reflect the correct method I used. I have added to my question that I am using 1.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/4gdJk/1/). I think this what you want!

```
$('body').on('click', '.add-remove-new:last', function() {
        $('tr.newService:first').clone().insertAfter($('tr.newService:last'));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346346/jquery-selector-doesnt-update-after-dynamically-adding-new-elements) seems to be dealing with the same problem and solves it using the `on()` or `delegate()` functions.