# JQuery selector still working after I remove the class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two jquery functions that work together, one depends on a class, another removes the class.

Once it is removed I would expect the functionality to stop working, but it carries on?

Whats going on?

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLSCt/2/), try it out for yourself.

```
<div class="container disabled"> 
    <a href="www.google.com">Go to Google</a>
</div>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" />Enable link</label>
```

The JS

```
$('.disabled > a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('should stop working');
});

$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
    $('.container').removeClass('disabled');
});
```

Comment: Even though you've removed the class, the action has already been bound to the element.  It doesn't automatically unbind.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It looks like you want to be using delegated event handlers rather than static event handlers.  Let me explain.

When you run a line of code like this:

```
$('.disabled > a').click(function (e) {
```

this installs an event handler on any objects that match the selector at that moment in time.  Those event handlers are then in place forever.  They no longer look at what classes any elements have.  So changing a class after you install a static event handler does not affect which elements have event handlers on them.

If you want dynanamic behavior where which elements respond to an event does depend upon what classes are present at any given moment, then you need to use delegated event handling.

With delegated event handling, you attach the event "permanently" to a parent and then the parent evaluates whether the child where the event originated matches the select each time the event fires.  If the child no longer matches the select, then the event handler will not be triggered.  If it does, then it will and you can add/remove a class to cause it to change behavior.

The general form of delegated event handlers are like this:

```
$("#staticParent").on("click", ".childSelector", fn);
```

You ideally want to select a parent that is as close to the child as possible, but is not dynamic itself.  In your particular example, you don't show a parent other than the body object so you could use this:

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".disabled > a", function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('should stop working');    
});
```

This code will then respond dynamically when you add remove the `disabled` class.  If the `disabled` class is present, the event handler will fire.  If it is not present, the event handler will not fire.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/pZeSA/

Other references on delegated event handling:

[jQuery .live() vs .on() method for adding a click event after loading dynamic html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752321/jquery-live-vs-on-method-for-adding-a-click-event-after-loading-dynamic-ht/8752376#8752376)

[jQuery .on does not work but .live does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985090/jquery-on-does-not-work-but-live-does/9985137#9985137)

[Should all jquery events be bound to $(document)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824549/should-all-jquery-events-be-bound-to-document/12824698#12824698)

[JQuery Event Handlers - What's the "Best" method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730277/jquery-event-handlers-whats-the-best-method/9730309#9730309)

[jQuery selector doesn't update after dynamically adding new elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346346/jquery-selector-doesnt-update-after-dynamically-adding-new-elements/9346385#9346385)

Comment: I actually discovered this just after I posted the question, but very detailed explenation.

Comment: Awesome answer. Thanks.

Comment: This is what I've been googling for for an hour. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3):

Changing the class after the event handler is bound has absolutely no effect as the event handler is **not** suddenly unbound, it's still bound to the same element.

You have to check for the class inside the event handler

```
$('.container > a').click(function (e) {
    if ( $(this).closest('.container').hasClass('disabled') ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});

$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
    $('.container').toggleClass('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bLSCt/3/)

Comment: Why not just use delegated event handlers so the event handler itself responds dynamically to added/removed classes?

Comment: @jfriend00 - That's one option, in this case I would just check for the presence of the class, but that's just me, either way is fine.

Comment: @jfriend00 - And that's what a delegated handler does, it checks if the target has that class, so just doing it myself I limit how many elements the event handler fires on, and I at least like to think that it's more efficient that way.

Answer (score 1):

When the selector runs, it gets a list of elements including the one in question and adds a click event handler to it.

Then you remove the class - so any subsequent jQuery selectors wouldn't get your element - but you have already attached the event so it will still fire.

The selector you have used runs on the line you declared it - it isn't lazily initialized when clicks happen.