# Jquery doesn't work on DOM change

Tags: jquery, delegates

In this page of multi-days festivals

https://www.metropub.net/www.italiajazz.it/calendario-festival

I added the following JS

https://www.metropub.net/www.italiajazz.it/sites/default/files/js_injector/js_injector_5.js

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() 
{
   console.log( "ready!" );
   jQuery('.fc-event-hori').on('mouseenter', function()
        {   
            x = jQuery(this).text();
            jQuery("a.fc-event-hori:contains('" + x + "')").css("background", "#fccd45"); 
            console.log('in');
        });
    jQuery('.fc-event-hori').on('mouseleave', function()
        { 
            x = jQuery(this).text();
            jQuery("a.fc-event-hori:contains('" + x + "')").css("background", "#15242a"); 
            console.log('out');
        });
});
```

for extend the hover of the mouse to the festival that are spanned over more than one week.

It works for the first page, but when I change the month, it doesn't work anymore.

Looking for solution on different threads, for example this link

[jQuery selector doesn't update after dynamically adding new elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346346/jquery-selector-doesnt-update-after-dynamically-adding-new-elements/9346385#9346385)

I modified my original code implementing the "delegated event handling", but my code still works only in the first page.

Am I missing something else?

Comment: Please read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Try to use $(document) with the event

Comment: jQuery(document).on('. fc-event-hori', 'mouseenter', function()
  {

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette: there's the link of the JS, is not ok? I thought put less mess in my question :(. Sorry for my misunderstad...

Comment: @SanjayKumar: I tried your solution, but it doesn't work either in the first page :D

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your issue by using [delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), like [Sanjay Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6769032/sanjay-kumar) suggested in comments.

**BUT**, strangely... It seems that you have another issue with the `mouseenter` and `mouseover` events. I think they possibly are prevented somewhere. I can't say.

I used the `mousemove` event to make it work.

I did this directly in the console. First I detached the event handler you had:

```
jQuery('.fc-event-hori').off('mouseenter');
jQuery('.fc-event-hori').off('mouseleave');
jQuery('.fc-event-hori').off('mouseover');
```

Then I inputted this handler code:

```
jQuery('.fullcalendar').on('mousemove mouseleave','.fc-event-inner', function(e){
  // Get the text.
  var x = jQuery(this).find('.fc-event-title').text();
  console.log(e.type);

  // Depending on the event, choose a color.
  if(e.type=="mousemove"){
    color="#fccd45";
  }else{
    color="#15242a";
  }

  // Use the text to lookup for the matching elements.
  jQuery(".fc-event-inner:contains("+x+")").css("background",color); 
});
```

And it worked perfectly.

Now, if I were you, I would try to find if there is a `.preventDefault()` somewere applyed on those events... It may not be that... But I would look. I would search all the files using [Agent Ransak](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/).

Then, I would look to upgrade the jQuery version. You are currently using 1.7.2, which is pretty old in my opinion. There are [guides](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/) to help on upgrading.